# Css scroll snap will not work with apple mobile web capable

Tags: ios, css, web

Css snap points are a nice alternative to javascript bases solutions. I realize that it is not a final spec, but webkit has adopted css snap points.

However, if you enable mobile web app capable meta then it fails

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/hpjtqewn/2/

Works perfect if you open it in safari on for example an ipad. Ignore the button, just scroll. Now pin this jsfiddle to your home screen and open it using the newly created shortcut. Mobile web app capable is loaded for jsfiddle and breaks the snap point functionality: you now have smooth scrolling instead of the snaps.

Using a polyfill as fallback does not fix the problem. Any suggestions without falling back to a full javascript solution?

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;

    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;

    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
    scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
    //scroll-snap-destination: 50% 50%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.a {
    background-color: green;
}
.b {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.c {
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>
<body>
<ol>
            <li class="a"></il>
            <li class="b"></il>
            <li class="c"></il>
            <li class="d"></il>
            <li class="e"></il>
            <li class="f"></il>
            <li class="g"></il>
            <li class="h"></il>
</ol>
<button id="scroll-to-c">Scroll to C</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added the code as you suggested @AndrewMyers

Answer (score 0):

There's a new addition to the draft specification that iOS 11 requires for scroll snapping to work. Add `scroll-snap-align: start;` to your scrolling items. [source: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/keep-snap-points-snapping.html]